# Successive glDrawArraysIndirect calls

Tags: c++, opengl

Let's say I want to launch a shader program with `glDrawArraysIndirect`, so I have a buffer which contains a vertex count at the start, followed by other data for the command. That buffer is bound as atomic counter buffer to the same shader program and the vertex shader is decreasing the vertex count by some rule. If the vertex count is not `0` at the end, the shader program should be relaunched. So this is done till the vertex count is `0`.

But what is the best way to know if the program needs the be relaunched? Is it possible to do this completely without reading back data(the vertex count)? If not, what is the most efficient way to read the data back? I'm currently running the shader program in a loop with a fixed number of iterations for which it's guaranteed to decrease the vertex count to `0`, but with this approach I'm throwing away time for draw calls with `0` vertices(around 3ms each), or is that still better than reading back data? I've got 10 draw calls, normally the vertex count is `0` at the 3rd - 6th draw call.

Comment: "*around 3ms each*" GPU time or CPU time?

Comment: I'd also really like to know what you're doing there. I have a feeling that you're over-complicating things.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas GPU time, i measured it with timer queries.

Comment: @thokra The example i gave is very simplified, actually the shader is building a sparse voxel octree, the vertex count tells how much voxels are left to insert in the tree, because multiple voxels can try to subdivide the same octree node only one is doing the subdivision, the other voxels are set on a "wait list" which is executed in a later pass to avoid waiting in one pass

Comment: @Nicole Bolas I don't know exactly how glMultiDrawArraysIndirect works, but if the commands are executed sequentially it's possible in one pass to change the command for the next pass. Thats not solving the problem to remove empty calls, but there would be less indirect draw calls on the CPU side, so maybe this would be the best approach. But if the commands are executed in parallel that wouldn't work, one pass depends on the previous, otherwise there wouldn't even be the need to launch multiple passes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any CPU readback operation is highly unlikely to be faster than leaving this stuff on the GPU. This is because it will have to provoke a full GPU/CPU synchronization, which will kill any hope of pipelining and asynchronous execution.

It's hard to say what an efficient way to do what you're doing is when you haven't said what exactly it is that you're doing. For example, would it be reasonable to develop a compute shader who's sole job is to compute compute how many iterations of each rendering command would be needed? If so, then the CS invocations could just build up a series of indirect rendering commands, which can be dispatched in one shot via `glMultiDrawIndirect`.